# Loop each forever

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

### I want this loop forever

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function news_hot() {
    $("div p").each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(1000 * i).queue(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hot_li ');
        $(this).prev().removeClass('hot_li');
      });
    });
  }
  news_hot();

});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>dfsdfsd</p>
  <p>dfsdfsd</p>
  <p>dfsdfsd</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at javascripts `setTimeout()` function instead.

Comment: What do you mean by I want this loop forerver?? Can you please give me any screenshots for it!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
You can see it in here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hobabe/1bjhdLpd/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval()` JavaScript function with specified time in milliseconds. The called function will run forever after interval time unless you stop it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        function news_hot() {
            $("div p").each(function (i) {
                $(this).delay(1000 * i).queue(function () {
                    $(this).addClass('hot_li ');
                    $(this).prev().removeClass('hot_li');
                });
            });
        }
        setInterval(news_hot(),5000);

    });
```

**UPDATED CODE** [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1bjhdLpd/18/)

```
function news_hot() {
        $("div p").each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(1000 * i).queue(function () {
                $("div p").removeClass("hot_li");
                $(this).addClass('hot_li');
                //$(this).prev().removeClass('hot_li');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
        });
}
setInterval(function(){news_hot()},5000);
```

`.dequeue()` function has been added to the code

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It not work.
You can see it in here: jsfiddle.net/hobabe/1bjhdLpd

Comment: I have changed the fiddle code, Now its running fine. Have a look:http://jsfiddle.net/1bjhdLpd/18/